# python encode/decode hex string to utf-8 string

Tags: python, utf-8, hex, decode, encode

I trying to decode a hex string in python.

```py
value = ""
for i in "54 C3 BC 72 20 6F 66 66 65 6E 20 4B 6C 69 6D 61".split(" "):
  value += chr(int(i, 16))
print(value)
```

Result:

> TÃ¼r offen Klima

Expected result should be "Tür offen Klima"
How can i make this work properly ?

Comment: You are "decoding" a unicode string, but your data is not unicode code point, but bytes of UTF-8. So: try with binarray (in UTF-8) and convert to unicode later

Comment: "Tür offen Klima" is encoded to "54FC72206F6666656E204B6C696D61". Please check your hex string, it simply looks wrong

Comment: @giacomo-catenazzi can you please explain it a litle more ? your commet is a litle bit to short for me to full understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is encoded as UTF-8, which means that you sometimes have to look at more than one byte to get one character. The easiest way to do this is probably to decode your string into a sequence of bytes, and then decode those bytes into a string. Python has built-in features for both:

value = bytes.fromhex("54 C3 BC").decode("utf-8")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the result of the string

> `"54 C3 BC 72 20 6F 66 66 65 6E 20 4B 6C 69 6D 61"`

is indeed

> TÃ¼r offen Klima

The proper hex string that result in "Tür offen Klima" is actually:

> `"54 FC 72 20 6F 66 66 65 6E 20 4B 6C 69 6D 61"`

Therefore, the code below would generate the result you expected:

```
value = ""
for i in "54 FC 72 20 6F 66 66 65 6E 20 4B 6C 69 6D 61".split(" "):
    value += chr(int(i, 16))
print(value)
```